# does a rectangular matrix have an inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know all square matrices have easily to identify inverses, but does that continue on with rectangular matrices?

Comment: No, but they can have right-inverse or left-inverse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Comment: Not all square matrices...

Answer (score 16):

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $m\neq n$, then $A$ cannot be both one-to-one and onto (by rank-nullity). So $A$ might have a left inverse or a right inverse, but it cannot have a two-sided inverse.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, not all square matrices have inverses.  Only the invertible ones do.  For example, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$ does not have an inverse.

And no, non-square matrices do not have inverses in the traditional sense.

There is the concept of a [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse).  To very briefly summarize the link, an $n \times m$ matrix $A$ has an $m \times n$ generalized inverse, denoted $A^g$, if $A^g$ satisfies $A A^g A = A$.

Comment: "generalized inverse" is also called (Moore)"pseudo-inverse" with most usual notation $A^+$.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I think that's a [specific type of generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse#Types_of_generalized_inverses) and not necessarily the same thing, although I'm not sure how "standard" any of this stuff is since I've never worked with it directly.